# Advantages of jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am more and more tempted to try jQueryUI. I'm sort of scared, though, that whenever a feature I need is missing, it will be hard to customize the widgets to my needs, so rolling my own widgets as needed may be a ore secure bet.

In particular what I'd like to know is:

1. How difficult is it to go beyond the basic themes? Say I want to widgets to match the design of my site, can I do this?
2. What if I need a widget to do a more complex interaction than it is designed for? For instance I created a widget for multiple inputs which works like this. The user writes the input in a text field. If he clicks on a + button, the input is copied in another place, and the input text is emptied, and so on. All the input is then submitted as a multiselect. Now, what if I wanted to use jQueryUI autocomplete on the input field? Can I expect that the other custom interaction will break the widget?

> In the end, is it worth the pain to use jQueryUI? I feel like I will lose more time in customizing it than I would in writing the widgets myself. Is this true?

Comment: Why do you consider it a pain to use jQuery UI? I would say it's one of the most enjoyable pieces in my ASP.NET MVC views... except for jQuery itself.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would say it is worth it to learn any library if you will be reproducing similar functionality. Even if you end up customizing it, your time spent on fixing bugs will most likely be far less.

Comment: I don't get your point. When one has enough confidence with a library, he may want to use that instead of reproducing its functionality. If you want/need to rewrite it, why learning the library? Ok, in theory you will be wiser when writing your own. But in practice one has limited time, and I think it would be spent better working on your own implementation.

Comment: I don't get your point. You say, that if I have limited time, I better spend it reimplementing stuff... jQuery UI, ASP.NET MVC, NHibernate, what else. Isn't it crazy? Aren't libraries and frameworks here to save time, which is especially good if it is limited? Why don't you write a C# compiler then, because *maybe* you won't be satisfied with the one that MS provides?

Comment: My only point is I personally would rather use code that has been heavily tested. Unless it is for academic exercise.

Comment: @Andrea: don't reinvent the wheel, but you should know how the wheel was created. I still study new libraries and write my own ones (if I have enough knowledge about it).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of jQuery plugins out there that are very good.  They can  all interoperate with jQuery UI.  I say take from jQuery UI what is useful to you, use other people's plugins where possible, and write your own plugins as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ThemeRoller application provided by Jquery-ui to build custom themes. Use the following link: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/Themeroller

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion jQueryUI is well-written and thouroughly designed.. just don't expect a 1000-controls library able to fit every possible need.

It is more or less a framework, a set of pieces you are encouraged to put together to assembly your stuff in a easier way.

See for instance http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API - it gives you directions on how to use it's CSS framework to give a consistent behaviour and look&feel to your pages. UI controls follow a similar idea..

Besides all it's well documented and mantained and there are lots of working examples for you to get an idea of it. You should get a glimpse of the way it's meant to be used to fully appreciate it: if you follow good guidelines I doubt you will get in troubles. And yes, you have jQuery under the hood, which is really a good engine!